# Topic Modeling issue in R

Tags: r, topic-modeling

Thanks a lot "PHIVER" after I removed the ??? items from the stopwords list the Gsub error was solved but now I have another error! Appreciate any assistance from the community-

> writeLines(as.character(corp[[30]]))
> Error in x$content[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

---

### title: "Text Mining"
output: html_document

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

#Load Libraries

```
library(tm)
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)
library(topicmodels)
library(tidytext)
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
library(kableExtra)
library(doParallel)
```

#Get and load PDF's

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:\\Users\\shaha\\Desktop\\Smart_literature_review", pattern = "pdf$", include.dirs = TRUE)

Rpdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))

setwd("C:\\Users\\shaha\\Desktop\\Smart_literature_review")
###Remember to manually set working directory
documents <- lapply(files, pdf_text)  #%>% read_lines())

corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(documents))

##Clean text
corp <-tm_map(corp,content_transformer(tolower))

#remove punctuation
corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
#Strip digits
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeNumbers)
#remove stopwords
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
#remove whitespace
corp <- tm_map(corp, stripWhitespace)
#Remove URL
urlPat<-function(x) gsub("(ftp|http)(s?)://.*\\b", "", x)
corp<-tm_map(corp, urlPat)
#Remove Email
emlPat<-function(x) gsub("\\b[A-Z a-z 0-9._ - ]*[@](.*?)[.]{1,3} \\b", "", x)
corp<- tm_map(corp, emlPat)

#Stem document
corp <- tm_map(corp,stemDocument)

#Remove stopwords
myStopwords <- c("can", "say","one","way","use",
"also","howev","tell","will",
"much","need","take","tend","even",
"like","particular","rather","said",
"get","well","make","ask","come","end",
"first","two","help","often","may",
"might","see","someth","thing","point",
"post","look","right" , "now","think","'ve",
"re","anoth","put","set","new","good",
"want","sure","kind","larg","yes","day","etc",
"quit","sinc","attempt","lack","seen","awar",
"littl","ever","moreov","though","found","abl",
"enough","far","earli","away","achiev","draw",
"last","never","brief","bit","entir","brief",
"great","lot","fig", "let", "follow", "ptrn
", "aalborg", "universitet", "proufbt", "ufbrm", "eufbect", "diufber", "ufbrst", "deufbn", "speciufbc", "signiufbc", "ufbnd", "vol", "thern", "ofrn", "journal", "tion", "andrn", "octob" )
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, myStopwords)
#inspect a document as a check
#Good practice to check every now and then
writeLines(as.character(corp[[30]]))

#Convert to document matrix
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
#remove sparse words
dtm <- removeSparseTerms(dtm,0.99)

#Alternative way to check words for several documents:
inspect(dtm[1:5,500:510])
```

#Run LDA

```
#convert rownames to filenames
rownames(dtm) <- files
#collapse matrix by summing over columns
freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
#length should be total number of terms
length(freq)
#create sort order (descending)
ord <- order(freq,decreasing=TRUE)
#List all terms in decreasing order of freq and write to disk
#freq[ord]

#Set parameters for Gibbs sampling
burnin <- 4000 
iter <- 4000
thin <- 500
seed <-list(3024,547,67,100000457,844)
nstart <- 5
keep <- 50
best <- TRUE

#For loop choosing different number of topics
#Currently selected 20 topics
system.time({
for (index in 1:1) {
  
#Number of topics
if(index == 1) {k=20} else if (index==2) {k=50} else if (index==3) {k=100}
  
#Run LDA using Gibbs sampling
ldaOut <-LDA(dtm,k, method= "Gibbs", control=list(nstart=nstart, seed = seed, best=best, burnin = burnin, iter = iter, thin=thin))

#write out results
#docs to topics
ldaOut.topics <- as.matrix(topics(ldaOut))

kable(ldaOut.topics) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed", "hover", "striped"), full_width = F, position ="center" )

#top 6 terms in each topic

ldaOut.terms <- as.matrix(terms(ldaOut,10))
 kable(ldaOut.terms) %>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed", "hover", "striped"), full_width = F, position ="center" )

#probabilities associated with each topic assignment
 #add names to prop table
 rownames(ldaOut@gamma) <- files
 topicProbabilities <- as.data.frame(ldaOut@gamma)
 kable(topicProbabilities, rownames =files) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed", "hover", "striped"), full_width = F, position ="center")  

 #Find relative importance of top 2 topics
topic1ToTopic2 <- lapply(1:nrow(dtm),function(x)
sort(topicProbabilities[x,])[k]/sort(topicProbabilities[x,])[k-1])
kable(topic1ToTopic2) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed", "hover", "striped"), full_width = F, position ="center" )

#Find relative importance of second and third most important topics
topic2ToTopic3 <- lapply(1:nrow(dtm),function(x)
sort(topicProbabilities[x,])[k-1]/sort(topicProbabilities[x,])[k-2])
 
kable(topic1ToTopic2) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed", "hover", "striped"), full_width = F, position ="center" )
#manually set working directory, to specify where the files should be saved.
setwd("C:\\Users\\cba\\OneDrive - Aalborg Universitet\\Papers\\Litterature Review\\Excel Filer")
if(index==1) {write.csv(files, file="document names.csv")}
write.csv(as.matrix(unlist(topic1ToTopic2)),file=paste("Topics", k, "Topic1ToTopic2.csv"))
write.csv(ldaOut.terms,file=paste("Topics", k, "Topic Overview.csv"))
write.csv(as.matrix(unlist(topic2ToTopic3)),file=paste("Topics", k,"Topic2ToTopic3.csv"))
write.csv(topicProbabilities,file=paste("Topics", k,"topicProbabilities.csv"))
write.csv(unlist(ldaOut.terms),file=paste("Topics", k,"Top10Words.csv"))
} # end for loop
})
```

#Cross validation

```
n <- nrow(dtm)

#Create training and test dataset
#in this case 75% is in the training set and 25% in the testset
splitter <- sample(1:n, round(n * 0.75))
train_set <- dtm[splitter, ]
test_set <- dtm[-splitter, ]

#----------------5-fold cross-validation, different numbers of topics----------------
#Use multiple cores for faster runtime
cluster <- makeCluster(detectCores(logical = TRUE) - 1) # leave one CPU spare...
registerDoParallel(cluster)

clusterEvalQ(cluster, {
   library(topicmodels)
})

#select parameters for cross validation
burnin <- 4000 
iter <- 4000
thin <- 500
seed <-list(3024,547,67,100000457,844)
keep <- 50
best <- TRUE
folds <- 5
splitfolds <- sample(1:folds, n, replace = TRUE)
candidate_k <- c(100,200) #c(2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 75) #, 100, 200, 300 candidates for how many topics
clusterExport(cluster, c("dtm", "burnin", "iter", "keep", "splitfolds", "folds", "candidate_k", "LDA"))

# we parallelize by the different number of topics.  A processor is allocated a value
# of k, and does the cross-validation serially.  This is because it is assumed there
# are more candidate values of k than there are cross-validation folds, hence it
# will be more efficient to parallelise
system.time({
results <- foreach(j = 1:length(candidate_k), .combine = rbind) %dopar%{
   k <- candidate_k[j]
   results_1k <- matrix(0, nrow = folds, ncol = 2)
   colnames(results_1k) <- c("k", "perplexity")
   for(i in 1:folds){
      train_set <- dtm[splitfolds != i , ]
      test_set <- dtm[splitfolds == i, ]
      
      fitted <- LDA(train_set, k = k, method = "Gibbs",
                    control = list(burnin = burnin, iter = iter, keep=keep ) )
      results_1k[i,] <- c(k, perplexity(fitted, newdata = valid_set))
   }
   return(results_1k)
}
})
stopCluster(cluster)


results_df <- as.data.frame(results)

#Export results to csv
write.csv(results_df,file=paste("cluster analysis.csv"))

#Plot
ggplot(results_df, aes(x = k, y = perplexity)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
   ggtitle("5-fold cross-validation of topic modelling ",
           "(ie five different models fit for each candidate number of topics)") +
   labs(x = "Candidate number of topics", y = "Perplexity")
```

Comment: Have you actually looked at the error? The gsub doesn't work, because you have words in your stopword list that have multiple question marks in them. That is where it fails.

Comment: Hi thanks for your guidance! I removed the stopwords with ??? now I get following error will you please guide me on this- > writeLines(as.character(corp[[30]]))
Error in x$content[[i]] : subscript out of bounds